# t.co messing up my url when posting through api

Tags: php, twitter

im using php and the twitter api library- when i send my message through the following code my links get messed up- as far as I know I'm using the standard twitter php api?

```
$result = $this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update', array('status' => $title));
```

before i post

```
testing link tracking http://bit.ly/tvHaWN
```

after i post

```
testing link tracking http://t.co/ptdXXNDH&lt;br&gt;
```

anyone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can suggest your `$title` variable contains of mixed text and HTML. Twitter statuses need to be plain text. Stripping tags should help.

Try to strip all HTML tags inside `$title` variable.

For example:

```
$result = $this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update', array('status' => strip_tags($title)));
```

Comment: i should have thought of that!